# Very High CPU Usage By Compiz on Radeon

Tags: 16.04, unity, graphics, compiz, radeon

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have AMD graphic card on my machine with following details. I have radeon driver installed.

```
inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.01hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 128 bits) GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7
```

My CPU usage gets very high even for normal activity like web browsing. In spite of using cooling pad machine temperature is getting so high that's getting hard shutdown.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks